# Radio buttons are too far spaced

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a website and I'm creating a form that allows the user to input their name, email, gender and date of birth. My problem is that I'm using     label for=""
to allow the css to have each section to align with the one above

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Email">Please enter e-mail:</label></td>
            <td><input id="email" type="text" name="email" title="email address" align="right" size="40"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Name">Please enter your full name:</label></td>
            <td><input id="name" type="text" name="name" title="name" align="right" size="40"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="DOB">Please enter your date of birth</label></td>
            <td><input id="DOB" type="date" name="DOB" title="DOB" align="right"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="gender">Please select your gender</label></td>
            <td><input id="male" type="radio" name="male" title="male"/>Male<td><input id="female" type="radio" name="female" title="female"/>Female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="submit"><input type ="submit" value="Submit"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

My css is:

```
label {
    margin-left:400px;
}
```

But my radio buttons are too far apart at the moment and I can't seem to get them to move closer together. The radio buttons can be seen at this image

[image: radio buttons]

If the image isn't showing you can see it here: http://www.howilearn2.com/student/NonStudentIndex.html

Comment: Just put the radiobuttons in 1 TD with colspan=2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You current are using a `<table>` to handle this formatting, however one of your radio buttons is placed in the third column (as opposed to being in the second with your other radio button).

Try placing them both in the same `<td>` element :

```
<td>
    <input id="male" type="radio" name="male" title="male"/>Male
    <input id="female" type="radio" name="female" title="female"/>Female
</td>
```

You can [see an example of this here](http://jsbin.com/suferu/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Thank you I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 2):

You placed the radio buttons in separate `td`'s, placing the female button in the third column, i.e. to the right of all the other fields. You can either fiddle around with `colspans` or simply place the two radio buttons in the same cell.

Two somewhat unrelated notes:

- Consider doing your form layout with `div` elements and css, instead of tables.
- Consider a third gender option, to be [more inclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genderqueer).

Answer (score 1):

I see you have chosen an answer, but I would like to offer an alternative answer. It may seem more complex, but I assure you that it helps in the long run:

**Overview**: I suggest a better [separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript) of content and design by using CSS for layout instead of the HTML.

**Explanation**: With today's focus on [responsiveness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) (that is, handling different screen sizes), tables are trouble. Mobile devices are now a big concern and tables often force a certain width, which may be a problem on the smaller screens of these devices. Also, if you wanted to change the design, you would either need to modify your HTML or add a number of table-specific things in CSS to override all of the default table styling in all the browsers. This can be a problem if the HTML ever gets reused in something like a template too.

We now have these awesome things called media queries that help us dynamically change styling based on the screen size. When following a "mobile-first" approach, you start designing for small screens first, then may expand content to fit larger screens using media queries. If you have the "table" defined in the CSS, you can have it easily change. (Ex: start as a vertical list and change to a table above certain screen widths)

**Example Responsive Solution***:

(After running the snippet, resize the browser window to see the effect)

```css
/* Mobile (notice you can make this something other than a table) */
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 25px;
}
.input-group:first-child, .input-submit:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.input-group, .input-submit {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.input-submit {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Larger-than-mobile */
@media (min-width : 768px) {
  .container { width: 758px; padding: 0px; }
  .form {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  .input-group {
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-row;
  }
  .input-label, .input-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    
    /* invisible border between "cells" to space them out */
    border: 15px solid transparent;
  }

  /* Remove outer borders (if you want, you can remove this) */
  .form .input-group:first-child > * {
    border-top: 0;
  }
  .form .input-group:last-child > * {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .form .input-group > *:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
  }
  .form .input-group > *:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="input-label" for="Email">Please enter e-mail:</label>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" title="email address" align="right" size="40" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="input-label" for="Name">Please enter your full name:</label>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" title="name" align="right" size="40"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="input-label" for="DOB">Please enter your date of birth:</label>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="DOB" type="date" name="DOB" title="DOB" align="right"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="input-label" for="gender">Please select your gender:</label>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="male" type="radio" name="male" title="male"/>Male
        <input id="female" type="radio" name="female" title="female"/>Female
      </div>
    </div>
    <label class="input-submit" for="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

*Class names and such are heavily based on [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)